# What are ARM64 system registers

Tags: embedded-systems, arm

I see in arm reference manuals they give info about certain configurations such as
**HCR_EL2, Hypervisor Configuration Register** ([HCR_EL2](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2021-12/AArch64-Registers/HCR-EL2--Hypervisor-Configuration-Register)), and what I read in books and reference manual is that ARM64 have x0-x31 + PC + SP. So where does HCR_EL2 comes into picture?

Comment: You are confusing the registers that are available to the usual user-mode software developer, and highly specialised registers that are used to control a hypervisor. Unless you develop hypervisors (and there are three guys at ARM, three at Google and another three at Apple doing that), you cannot touch these registers and shouldn't even try.

Answer (score 3):

I'd point you at the documentation, but you've already found it. X0-X31 are the "general purpose" registers, for use by user programs. All the others are "architecture specific" registers, and they have these basic properties:

- you can't use them as input and output of operations, you can only move them in and out of a general purpose register
- values in them change the behavior of the processor, or report its state
- quite often they cannot be accessed outside of one of the privileged modes.

Generally you don't need to worry about them unless you're writing an operating system.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that for most of them, you can't even access them using a conventional move instruction like a general purpose register, you need to use the coprocessor move instructions: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/cb/System-Level-Architecture/Protected-Memory-System-Architecture--PMSA-/About-the-system-control-registers-for-PMSA/About-system-control-register-accesses?lang=en

Comment: So these registers are also on ARM core ? Where do these exists?

Comment: They are part of the core, yes. As the comment says you need to use a special instruction to read/write them, and usually to be privileged.